# How to pagination from multiple query yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

i want to pagination my results in yii2.but from more than one table.
here is my action code of site controller:

```html
<?
public function actionPagination_product(){
$query=Product::find();

$count=$query->count();

$pagination=new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count, 'defaultPageSize' => 1]);

 $models = $query->offset($pagination->offset)
      ->limit($pagination->limit)
      ->all();
   
      return $this->render('pagination_pro', [
      'models' => $models,
      'pagination' => $pagination,
   ]);

}


?>
```

and here is my view:

```html
<?php
   use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
<?php foreach ($models as $model): ?>

 <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?= $model->title; ?></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text"><?= $model->id; ?></p>
  <p class="list-group-item-text"><?= $model->body; ?></p>
  </a>
</div>

  
   <br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php
   // display pagination
   echo LinkPager::widget([
      'pagination' => $pagination,
   ]);
?>
```

this is for searching in multiple tables and i can not join them.

for example i want to read Report::find() in this pagination

how to do that?

Comment: You should also show the `Product::find();` method

Comment: i mean i want to read from other tables . how to do that for other tables?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding your questions correctly. But if your problem is "and i can not join them.". You can join the tables you want to show using something like that in your controller:

```
$model = Report::find()
->join('INNER JOIN', 'otherModel', 'otherModel.report_id = report.id');
->all();
```

This way you will have all the data you need in the variable $model and then you can do anything you want with it.